# How can we associate an image & textfield with a specific Domain in Drupal 7?

Tags: domain-access

I am using two subdomains in my drupal project. I would like to associate image and textfields with specefic domain only.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/domain_fields

this module works for me as it restrict fields to specific content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Domain Fields](http://drupal.org/project/domain_fields) module works for me as it restricts fields to specific content type on specific domains.